# Vagrant networking error with 2 networks cards (1 inactive)

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I've got 2 network cards on my Linux host machine.  eth0 is flaky, so I don't use it (ifconfig eth0 down).  eth1 is set up for DHCP.

In my Vagrantfile, I have

```
  config.vm.network :private_network, type: 'dhcp'
```

This works. Sort of.  The windows guest machine comes up with working networking on "Ethernet 2".  It also has an inactive "Ethernet" connection.  But I get an error on vagrant up, and it doesn't run my Chef recipes.  The vagrant error is

```
==> win10: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
The following WinRM command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet 2" dhcp
if ($?) { exit 0 } else { if($LASTEXITCODE) { exit $LASTEXITCODE } else { exit 1 } }

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:
```

I've tried 
    config.vm.network :private_network, type: 'dhcp', adapter: '2'

but that gives

```
 undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

from a call stack of

```
blah/configure_networks.rb:25:in `each'
blah/configure_networks.rb:25:in `configure_networks'
blaah/lib/vagrant/capability_host.rb:111:in `call'
blaah/lib/vagrant/capability_host.rb:111:in `capability'
```

Answer (score 1):

from [vagrant networking doc](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html)

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", auto_config: false

  # manual ip
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    run: "always",
    inline: "ifconfig eth1 192.168.0.17 netmask 255.255.255.0 up"

end
```